# Kafka Log4j appender not sending messages

Tags: java, log4j, apache-kafka

i am quite new ot apache Kafka and log4j. i am trying to send my log messages into Kafka. Here is my log4j properties file

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L %% %m%n

log4j.appender.KAFKA=kafka.producer.KafkaLog4jAppender
log4j.appender.KAFKA.BrokerList=localhost:9092
log4j.appender.KAFKA.Topic=kfkLogs


log4j.appender.KAFKA.SerializerClass=kafka.producer.DefaultStringEncoder
log4j.appender.KAFKA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.KAFKA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L %% - %m%n

log4j.logger.logGen=DEBUG, KAFKA
```

however, i am not able to receive any messages in my consumer. I have tested the consumer with some other producer code and it works fine.

also, i get this warning

```
log4j:WARN No such property [serializerClass] in kafka.producer.KafkaLog4jAppender.
```

**Edit**

and here is the code that generates my log messages

```
    package logGen;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class TestLog4j {

    static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(TestLog4j.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        log.debug("Debug message");

        log.info("Info message");

        log.error("Error Message");

        log.fatal("Fatal Message");

        log.warn("Warn Message");

        log.trace("Trace Message");
    }

}
```

Also, if i write the log messages to a file by using something like

```
log4j.appender.KAFKA=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.KAFKA.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.KAFKA.File=logs/server.log
```

i can see the log messages in the server.log file

thanks for the suggestions everyone. i think the weird behavior that i see might be related to my kafka set up. here are the contents of my server.properties file which i use to start up my kafka server. can you see anything odd about it ?

```
broker.id=0

port=9092

num.network.threads=3

num.io.threads=8

socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400

socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400

socket.request.max.bytes=104857600

log.dirs=/Users/xyz/kafka/kafka-logs

num.partitions=1

num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1

log.retention.hours=168

log.segment.bytes=1073741824

log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000

log.cleaner.enable=false

zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181

zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000

delete.topic.enable=true
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have took a look at the source code of KafkaLog4jAppender.scala and here are the **valid** and **exhaustive** properties for Kafka log4j appender as of version 0.8.2.1 : topic, brokerList, compressionType, requiredNumAcks, syncSend.

The **log4j.properties** that worked for me is below :

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, stdout

log4j.logger.logGen=DEBUG, KAFKA

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L %% %m%n

log4j.appender.KAFKA=kafka.producer.KafkaLog4jAppender
log4j.appender.KAFKA.topic=LOG
log4j.appender.KAFKA.brokerList=localhost:9092
log4j.appender.KAFKA.compressionType=none
log4j.appender.KAFKA.requiredNumAcks=0
log4j.appender.KAFKA.syncSend=true
log4j.appender.KAFKA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.KAFKA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L %% - %m%n
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `KAFKA` to your `log4j.rootLogger` like this:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, KAFKA
```

This will add the `KAFKA` appender to your rootLogger.

Comment: i'm afraid that did not solve the problem. but i think i found the solution. please see the answer

Answer (score 1):

i had to specify

log4j.appender.KAFKA.producer.type=async

log4j.logger.logGen.TestLog4j=TRACE, KAFKA

and that seems to work. however i experience a delay of 10-30 seconds. Specifically, if i publish right now and can see the messages in teh consumer, then the next time i publish has to be about 30 secs later else i dont see anything in my consumer. any ideas on why this might be happening ? maybe its an eclispe issue ?

Comment: Have you tried log4j.appender.KAFKA.producer.type=sync ? Async producer buffers incomming messages (by time or by number of msgs) to optimize network throughput. It is normal that you observe a delay.

Comment: thanks, i tried the sync option but now nothing seems to be passing at all ! which does not make sense logically. i believe this might have something to do with how i have kafka set up. please see the edit for my server.properties file

Answer (score 1):

log4j.appender.KAFKA.SerializerClass=kafka.producer.DefaultStringEncoder

could you try

log4j.appender.KAFKA.Serializer=kafka.producer.DefaultStringEncoder

Instead?

I believe the async mode of sending msgs does so by batching, hence the delay, have you you tried sending using sync?

Comment: thanks, but i get a warning

log4j:WARN No such property [serializer] in kafka.producer.KafkaLog4jAppender.

also, if i change the mode to sync, nothing seems to be passed at all !